# Dax - grouping data for Sankey Chart in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to group my data based on the column "Type" and prepare a sankey chart with Country data.
The desire results is to have value by country for type - "MLA" and value for country for type "Sponsor". The tricky part is that there is a lot of duplicated information and it needs to be by unique ID.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could look into potentially using the GROUPBY function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/groupby-function-dax

You would add this to a blank table, and then it would create a summarised version of the original data table but summarised into the columns that you choose.